# Incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function bzero

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I am new to c programming and I am currently trying to understand the concepts of Network programming. There is a simple server code which I am trying to run on Kali linux( Debian based linux system) but there are quite a few errors which I am not able to debug. Please have a look at my code.

### code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define SA  struct sockaddr
#define MAXLINE 4096

int main(int argc,int **argv)
{
    int roockfd,confd;
    socklen_t len;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr,cliaddr;
    char buff[MAXLINE];
    time_t ticks;

    roockfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

    bzero(&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(13);
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    Bind(roockfd,(SA*)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));

    Listen(roockfd,5);

    for(; ;)            
    {
        len=sizeof(cliaddr);

        confd= Accept(roockfd,(SA*)&cliaddr,&len);
        printf("Connection from %s, port %d\n",
            Inet_ntop(AF_INET,&cliaddr.sin_addr,buff,sizeof(buff)),
            ntohs(cliaddr.sin_port));

        ticks=time(NULL);
        snprintf(buff,sizeof(buff),"%.24s\r\n", ctime(ticks));
        printf(confd,buff,strlen(buff));
        close(confd);
    }
}
```

Awaiting your valuable responses.

Comment: Add `#include <strings.h>` for the `bzero` error/warning. If there are more errors please paste them exactly into your question.

Comment: There is no error handling anywhere in this code. You say there are errors, but you don't show them, or indicate which lines are erroring.

Comment: When C was first standardized in 1989 by ANSI, the document specified a `<string.h>` header in which there is a function called `memset` for setting a range of memory to a given byte value, such as zero. At that moment, `bzero` became obsolete. Today, it is 2016.

Comment: [Read the `bzero` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/bzero.3.html).

Comment: @Kaz There has never been `strings.h` in ANSI C or ISO C.  It is in POSIX. `memset` is defined by `string.h`

Comment: It would be better to use neither bzero nor memset, and use `struct sockaddr_in servaddr = { 0 };`

Comment: You can also initialize these structures to zero using the syntax for doing so: `struct sockaddr_in servaddr = { 0 }, cliaddr = { 0 };`.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience guys as I am new to this site. I will be more specific with errors/warnings I am facing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several errors:

1. To use `bzero`, include `#include <strings.h>` in the file. Note that `bzero` is an obsolete function used in BSD, you should consider use `memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr))` instead.
2. The functions `Bind`, `Listen`, `Inet_ntop` and `Accept` are not standard socket functions, either you are mistakenly capitalized them, if this is the case, change to `bind`, `listen`, `inet_ntop` and `accept`. Or they are customized wrappers of the socket interface, if that is the case, include the corresponding headers in the file.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a version of that code which compiles. Please compare it to your original version and try to understand the changes. I agree with @fluter's suggestions. There are a couple more things needed to get it to compile. I have in no way verified its operation or behaviour, however.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#define SA  struct sockaddr
#define MAXLINE 4096

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int roockfd, confd;
    socklen_t len;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cliaddr;
    char buff[MAXLINE];
    time_t ticks;

    roockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(13);
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    bind(roockfd, (SA *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

    listen(roockfd, 5);

    for (; ;) {
        len = sizeof(cliaddr);

        confd = accept(roockfd, (SA *)&cliaddr, &len);
        printf("Connection from %s, port %d\n",
               inet_ntop(AF_INET, &cliaddr.sin_addr, buff, sizeof(buff)),
               ntohs(cliaddr.sin_port));

        ticks = time(NULL);
        snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), "%.24s\r\n", ctime(&ticks));
        write(confd, buff, strlen(buff));
        close(confd);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! it works now. Is it only the header files that I have missed?

Comment: I suggest to use a diff program (`vimdiff`, for example) to compare the two side-by-side. Also, you can use `-Wall` and `-Werror` options to the compiler in the future to help catch some issues, earlier.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir!!